# Output Json Array in cpp using nlohmann

Tags: c++, arrays, json, nlohmann-json

I created json objects using nlohmann library with this code:

```
nlohmann::json dataJson;
auto data = dataJson.array();

data[0]["message"] = "String";
data[0]["timestamp"] = 123;
```

The output is

```
{"message":"String", "timestamp": 123}
```

but i want the output to be

```
[{"message":"String", "timestamp": 123}]
```

in an array in order to have the ability to have multiple messages.

So i want to ask what is the best way to add the values in the array, because when I print it, the ouput of the array is null.

I am new at cpp so I want to apologize for the question if is considered too easy, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you "output" the result? I cannot reproduce your issue. If I dump your exact code using `std::cout << data.dump();` the result is `[{"message":"String","timestamp":123}]`... Just a guess, but do you output it like `std::cout << data[0].dump();` (notice the first element of data, instead the entire data)...

Comment: well, actually yes, you are right, because I was trying to get it in a loop, sorry. But Richard also helped a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nlohmann_json is a very useful library but it does have a few quirks. I find it's best to be explicit about intent.

Lambdas can be very useful here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

int main() {

  auto make_object = []
  {
    auto result = nlohmann::json::object();
    result["message"] = "String";
    result["timestamp"] = 123;
    return result;
  };

  auto make_array = [&make_object]
  {
    auto result = nlohmann::json::array();
    result.push_back(make_object());
    return result;
  };

  auto data = make_array();
  std::cout << data.dump() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
[{"message":"String","timestamp":123}]
```